# Как хранить time в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

В чем отличие? Мне нужно фиксировать время добавления сообщения. А лучше показывать, сколько времени прошло с момента добавления, так проще. Что использовать? Какой тип таблицы создать в mysql и как добавлять в таблицу? Сейчас я использую datetime и добавляю с помощью NOW().

Answer (score 2):

Лично я храню время в формате unix, а потом преобразую с помощью метода :)

```
function di_time($time = null) {

    $date = date('j M в H:i', $time);

    if (date('j n Y', $time) == date('j n Y', time())) {
        $date = 'сегодня в '.date('H:i', $time);
    } elseif (date('j n Y', $time) == date('j n Y', time() - 86400)) {
        $date = 'вчера в '.date('H:i', $time);
    }

    return strtr($date,
        array(
            'Jan' => 'Янв',
            'Feb' => 'Фев',
            'Mar' => 'Мар',
            'Apr' => 'Апр',
            'May' => 'Мая',
            'Jun' => 'Июн',
            'Jul' => 'Июл',
            'Aug' => 'Авг',
            'Sep' => 'Сен',
            'Oct' => 'Окт',
            'Nov' => 'Ноя',
            'Dec' => 'Дек'
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В таблице int(11). При вставке пхп-шная `time();` Однозначно.